# c++ call superclass constructor with calculated arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

probably it's super easy, but can someone tell me how I can call the superclass' constructor with arguments calculated in the subclass' constructor? something like this:

```
class A{
  A(int i, int j);
};

class B : A{
  B(int i);
};

B::B(int i){
  int complex_calculation_a= i*5;
  int complex_calculation_b= i+complex_calculation_a;
  A(complex_calculation_a, complex_calculation_b);
}
```

//edit: i edited the example so that the superclass takes two arguments which have a relation to each other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you cannot express your calculation in a single-line expression, add a static function, and call it in the way you normally call the constructor of the superclass:

```
class B : A{
public:
    B(int i) : A(calc(i)) {};
private:
    static int calc(int i) {
        int res = 1;
        while (i) {
            res *= i--;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

**EDIT** Multiple-argument case:

```
class B : A{
public:
    B(int i) : A(calc_a(i), calc_b(i)) {};
private:
    static int calc_a(int i) {
        int res = 1;
        while (i) {
            res *= i--;
        }
        return res;
    }
    static int calc_b(int i) {
        int complex_a = calc_a(i);
        return complex_a+10;
    }
};
```

Comment: okay - and if the superclass constructor takes several arguments?

Comment: @Mat You would need to define separate function for calculating the value of each parameter that you cannot or do not want to "inline" as an expression.

Comment: but the calculated arguments may depend on each other - how can i solve that with different functions?

Comment: @Mat Unfortunately, you would need to repeat the same calculation several times. I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
B::B(int i) 
    : A(i * 5) 
{}
```

With C++11, a more complex way is

```
B::B(int i)
    : A(([](int x) { return 5 * x; })(i))
{}
```

For complex cases, a protected `init` function is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Only like this:

```
class A{
  A(int i);
};

class B : A{
  B(int i);
};

B::B(int i) : A(i*5) {
}
```

The call to the parent's constructor can only come in the initialization list. Which means, that whatever you're calculating must be known **before** B is fully constructed (i.e.: you can't call a `B` member function, unless its `static`, but only to rely on the parameters passed to `B`)

Comment: okay - in this case my example was bad. I need to do several function calls, loops, conditional branching and so on to calculate the arguments

Comment: @Mat - as I said - you can only do this in external function (either global or a static class member, or a member function of an object passed to `B`). `B` doesn't exist when `A` is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct A
{
    A(int);
};

struct B : public A
{
    B()
        : A(5) // "initialisation list"
    {}
};
```

You have to do this inside the list, but you can use a function.
Edit: If you use a function, you probably want to make it a private static member of B.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
public:
   A(int i){}
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int i):A(i*5){}
};
```