# Construct object without arguments where superclass requires arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm implementing a class that inherits from a superclass. The superclass requires arguments for its constructor. I would like the subclass to be instantiatable without requiring arguments. The superclass looks like this:

```
class OtherClass {
public:
    OtherClass(YetAnotherClass *yac);
};
class SuperClass {
public:
    SuperClass(OtherClass *c);
};
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class MyClass : public SuperClass {
public:
  MyClass() : SuperClass(OtherClass(YetAnotherClass)) {}
};
```

In order to avoid having to do something like this when instantiating a member of `MyClass`:

```
YetAnotherClass * only_used_once = YetAnotherClass();
OtherClass * also_used_just_once = OtherClass(only_used_once);
MyClass what_i_actually_want = MyClass(also_used_just_once);
```

Is this possible? [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539550/c-call-superclass-constructor-with-calculated-arguments) showed the solution of creating a static method that produces the arguments needed for the parent constructor, but I would hope there's a simpler way to get there.

Comment: Why are your constructors taking arguments by pointer?

Comment: Because they're not mine ;) I would also much prefer references, when a pass by copy is not desired.

Comment: *Superclass* is javaspeak that does not make sense in C++ due to multiple inheritance. Try to use *base class* and *derived class* instead. Also your problem will probably go away when you know about [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @initializer: how is "base class" more appropriate than "superclass"? Will it cause any trouble if someone says something like "class A has superclasses B1 and B2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With :

```
struct DataClass
{
    DataClass() : yetAnotherClass(), otherClass(&yetAnotherClass) {}

    YetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass;
    OtherClass otherClass;
};
```

If each instance of `MyClass` owns the other class you may do the following:

```
class MyClass : private DataClass, public SuperClass
{
public:
  MyClass() : DataClass(), SuperClass(&this->otherClass) {}
};
```

else they share the other class and you may do:

```
class MyClass : public SuperClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : SuperClass(&dataClass.otherClass) {}
private:
    static DataClass dataClass;
};

DataClass MyClass::dataClass;
```